# Postfix deliver mail for orginal destination + BCC - but only for one email

Tags: postfix, domain, rewrite, wildcard

I have postfix with virtual users, I'm looking for solution, tried google it, but no luck.

I want to achieve this one:

```
mail for admin@*
should be delvered to admin@* and BCC for webmaster@*
```

I tried to do it by *recipient_bcc_maps* and something like:

```
/admin@(.+)/ admin@$1, webmaster@$1
```

but it doesn't work.

(Logs watched, postmap done ;) )

Any idea with example? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, solution by myself:

Add file with pcre:

```
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps.cf
```

In file:

```
/^admin@(.*)/ admin@$1,webmaster@$1
```

Reload, done.